# Making User Variable From config.toml Show Up In Page Body

Tags: configuration, hugo, user-defined

I'm creating a page. I have a site-wide parameter defined in my default config.toml file like this.

```
[Params]
tdName= "Mr. Tournament Director"
```

In my page I'm writing:

`{{ .Site.Params.tdName }}`

Rather than the string in quotes, the code below that is litterally showing up when I run the "hugo server" command. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify Go template code in a file in the `content` directory, you need to use a Hugo shortcode. For example, you could use this inline shortcode:

```
{{< tdname.inline >}}
{{ site.Params.tdName }}
{{< /tdname.inline >}}
```

To use inline shortcodes, as I do above, you need to set `enableInlineShortcodes` to true in your config file.

Note that:

- `site.Params.tdName` is usually equivalent to `.Site.Params.tdName` but is better because it is context free (no leading dot (.))
- Hugo has some weird case sensitivity issues so I recommend that you change `tdName` to `td_name` or `tdname` or something without upper case characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Hugo's built-in `param` shortcode like this:

```
{{< param tdName >}}
```

To learn about this built-in shortcode, see:

- https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#param
- https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/tpl/tplimpl/embedded/templates/shortcodes/param.html